# Modular Marionette Application

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, modular

I'm trying to structure my backbone/marionette application prior to coding it. I really want to make it very modular (aka I want to be able to pull and plugin some piece of nested functionality for the site. I want all the routes initialized right away, so I can bookmark pages as well. I'm struggling to set this up, though.

Has anyone found a good approach to setting up an application where the AppRouter would load all of the routes in the modules, but have an effective way of lazy loading the rest of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to really explain in any short form. I'd highly recommend watching all of the backbonerails.com episodes. He does a fantastic way of showing how to modularize your app.